# About swift5 and alamofire5,how to use AF.request to check if login sucessed or failed?

Tags: swift, authentication, asynchronous, request, alamofire

I want to use `AF.request` to implement login, this is my code:

```swift
import Alamofire
var loginResult: Bool = false
func login() -> Bool {
    let parameters: [String: String] = [
        "password": "Adgj!4567",
        "username": "admin",
    ]
    var a = AF.request("http://192.168.64.2/logins.php", method: .post, parameters:parameters,encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .httpBody)).response{
        response in
        if let data = response.data {
            let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            if result.contains("Login Success!"){
                print (result)
                loginResult = true
            }else {
                loginResult = false
            }
        }
    }
    return loginResult
}
```

When I called `login()`, I got response like this:

[image]

send request worked, but `loginResult` has been always false, and I know that because AF is async, my problem is that I want to check if loginResult's value is true and go to another page, but it is always false, what should i do???

ContentView.swift like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isLoginValid: Bool = false
    @State private var shouldShowLoginAlert: Bool = false
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack {
                Label("username", systemImage: "")
                Label("password", systemImage: "")
            }
            VStack {
                TextField("input username", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("input password", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
        }
        .padding()
            NavigationLink(destination: infoInputView(),isActive: self.$isLoginValid) {
                Text("Login")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if login(){
                            self.isLoginValid = true
                            }
                        else{
                                self.shouldShowLoginAlert = true
                            }
                     
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
             .navigationBarTitle("Login Screen")
             .alert(isPresented: $shouldShowLoginAlert) {
              Alert(title: Text("Email/Password incorrect"))
        }
        .padding(.all, 50.0)
        }
    }
            }
        

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}
```

My mother tongue is not english, I hope you can understand me.

Comment: Please, include in your question the raw response body that you are getting. (the `result` string)

Comment: i added ,thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

i have got a wrong way,the right way is this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isLoginValid: Bool = false
    @State private var shouldShowLoginAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var loginResult: Bool = false
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack {
                Label("用户名", systemImage: "")
                Label("密码", systemImage: "")
            }
            VStack {
                TextField("请输入用户名", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("请输入密码", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
        }
        .padding()
            NavigationLink(destination: infoInputView(),isActive: self.$isLoginValid) {
                Text("Login")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        login()
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
             .navigationBarTitle("Login Screen")
             .alert(isPresented: $shouldShowLoginAlert) {
              Alert(title: Text("Email/Password incorrect"))
        }
        .padding(.all, 50.0)
        }
    }
            }

    

    func login() {
        let parameters: [String: String] = [
                "password": "Adgj!4567",
                "username": "admin",
            ]
        var a = AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters:parameters,encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .httpBody))
        a.response{
            response in
            if let data = response.data {
                let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                if result.contains("Login Success!") {
                    isLoginValid = true
                }else {
                    shouldShowLoginAlert = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}
```